# Flash AS3 on URLLoader.load POST - getting http status=0 and no data. Works in Flash IDE

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, http-status-codes, ioerror

I am making rest calls with a `urlload.load(urlRquest)`.

also

```
  urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
  urlRequest.contentType = "application/xml";
```

When I make the calls within the Flash IDE, I get HTTPStatusEvent.status = 400 (or whatever) when an error occurs. And the IOErrorEvent.data contains xml (or sometimes a string).

However, when I run the swf in a browser (Firefox Mac or PC), the `HTTPStatusEvent.status = 0`, and the `IOErrorEvent.data` is empty. (Interestingly in Safari Mac, I do get the 400 status, but still no data.)

Any ideas on what may be occurring? (I need my errors!)

Comment: check crossdomain or sandbox settings ... don't know if they're responsible for _this_ problem but most of the time they are. http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html#117502

Comment: Are you also listening for `SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR`?

Comment: Good idea with SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, but unfortunately no security errors occurred. But I will double check that the crossdomain file is set for that server. Interestingly, there is urlloader data when the call is successful.

Comment: Did some more testing. First off the crossdomain file is correct. If the service returns a 200 status instead of an error status, the payload (data) does make it through.

Answer (score 3):

Running the swf in Firefox will always generate a 0, since Firefox does not pass status codes to the flash player, according to the [action script reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/HTTPStatusEvent.html#HTTP_STATUS).

Answer (score 0):

Likely when you're running the swf in Flash the `Security.sandboxType` property is **localTrusted** which leads to fully granted access to the outside. But when you run it in a browser it appears to be **localWith...**.

Try to do following:

1) compile it with `-use-network=true`

[ADDED]

In Flash, the setting is under "Publish Settings", Flash tab. The name is "Local playback security". So you need to set it to "Access network only" before you publish a swf.

You can also switch the "-use-network" flag of a swf file after publish by using the Adobe's [Local Content Updater](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html#lcu).

[/ADDED]

2) provide access to the network in your HTML wrapper.

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="100" height="100">  
  <param name="allowNetworking" value="all">  
  <param name="movie" value="moviename.swf">  
  <param name="quality" value="high">  
   <embed src="moviename.swf" width="100" height="100" quality="high"></embed>  
</object>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Daniel B, you need to update the Publish Settings according to my answer.